# WebClient website login

Tags: c#, authentication, browser, webclient, html

I have difficulties logging in to a webpage (http://hurt.prosto.pl); all the time it returns to the login page source... Any idea how to fix it?

```
var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
loginData.Add("username", username);
loginData.Add("password", password);

var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
client.BaseAddress = @"http://hurt.prosto.pl/accounts/login/?next=/hurt/";
client.UploadValues("http://hurt.prosto.pl/accounts/login/?next=/hurt/", "POST", loginData);

// now you are logged in and can request pages    
string htmlSource = client.DownloadString("http://hurt.prosto.pl/hurt/myorders/--/category/all1/");
webBrowser2.DocumentText = htmlSource;
```

This is my CookieAwereWebClient class:

```
namespace HTMLParser
{
    internal class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Anwser with solution for ppl like me :) gl

```
string loginData = "username=***&password=***&next=/hurt/";
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string cookie = string.Empty;
            wc.BaseAddress = @"http://hurt.prosto.pl/accounts/login/";


            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: identity");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
            wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");



            wc.UploadString("http://hurt.prosto.pl/accounts/login/", "POST", loginData);
            cookie = wc.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"].ToString();
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
            wc.UploadString("http://hurt.prosto.pl/accounts/login/", "POST", loginData);
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = wc.DownloadString("http://hurt.prosto.pl/hurt/myorders/--/category/all1/");
```

Comment: You are logging in twice, no need to do that. Just set the cookie and go to your target page. Also, you do not need to set Content-Type, `WebClient` does that automatically.

Answer (score 3):

```
string string loginData = "username=***&passowrd=***&next=/hurt/";

WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
wc.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
string response = wc.UploadString("http://hurt.prosto.pl/accounts/login/", "POST", loginData);
```

Cookies:

```
// general retrieve
string cookie = wc.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"].ToString();

// general send
wc.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
```

Comment: Thnx for Your time! I will try to test it right now, i will post info after.

Comment: Check the update for the content-type definition (mandatory for posting forms)

Comment: there is no method like "ContentType"

Comment: wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
also not working - login page string return

Comment: A lot of misunderstanding. One more try.

Comment: Ok, i used code that u write below. I am one step closer it want to login but this page require cookies containter. How to add it to code in your anwser?

Comment: Make your first request with a get (do not post for login) and read the header "Set-Cookie" from the response. Then add what is read to request header (wc.Headers.Add("Cookie", whatisread) and you're done. The step of reading (and possibly updating with a newer value) and sending back a cookie is mandatory for all steps after the initial one.

Comment: Ok, i will try, thnx for your time and advice!

Comment: Ok I'm a newbie but still trying... Could u help me how to get and later set cookies?

Comment: Suprice gues what :P "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at // general retrieve

Comment: Sorry. You have to move on on your own. You deny to read and try when it's obvious that you have to start from A (this is what you do as a newbie), but you're asking me to do your job.

Comment: Did it :D, meaby sh1t code but working :) Thnx for your time again

Comment: Well done. More read and try = easier future and better coding.