# WebClient login issue C#

Tags: c#, authentication, webclient

```
<form name="login" action="https://www.Testsite.com/html/login.jsp" method="post">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
        <input type="text" name="login_name" id="login_name" autocomplete="username" placeholder="User Name">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_key" value="-963293021">
        <input type="submit" id="html_login_btn" value="Login">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" checked="true">
            <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
            <a href="/html/forgot_name.jsp">Forgot User Name?</a>
            <a href="/html/forgot.jsp">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to login to a website using webclient, I have made a scraper to test but the page I wanna try to scrape requires a user to login before viewing the page. The issue I'm having is when I try to login it tries to download the login.jsp file. I have read a couple posts on this site that describes how to do it and is also how I did the code below. I don't want just the answer because I'm trying to learn this.

If you reply with a solution could you point out what I did wrong also, This is the code I am using to try to login with:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collection =
        new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        collection.Add("login_name", "ImUser");
        collection.Add("password", "Thispass");
        client.Proxy = null;
        byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://www.Testsite.com/html/login.jsp", "post", collection);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("login.jsp", result);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("login.jsp");
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Status);
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string loginData = "login_name=ImUser&passowrd=ThisPas&next=/";

    WebClient web = new WebClient();

    web.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5");
    web.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    web.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
    web.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    web.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    web.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    string response = web.UploadString("https://www.testsite.com/html/login.jsp", "POST", loginData);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> players = new List<string>();
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    String html = web.DownloadString("http://www.testsite.com");
    MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<a href=""\s*(.+?)\s*"">", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    foreach (Match m in m1)
    {
        if (m.Groups[1].Value != "")
        {
            string player = m.Groups[1].Value;
            players.Add(player);
        }
    }
    listbox1.DataSource = players; 
}
```

Comment: have you looked at any of the `many examples` posted here on `SO` here is a good starting point [WebClient Website Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074731/webclient-website-login)

Comment: That example still doesn't log me in, yet it also no longer tries to download the page.

Comment: can you post the updated code

Comment: Edited post with the updated code